# Determining the convergence/divergence of a special sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $$x_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n e^{2\pi i H_k}$$

where $H_k$ is the $k^{th}$ harmonic number. Does $ \{ x_n \}$ converge or diverge? A friend and I have tried this but couldn't conclude anything. Based on a python script, the norm seems to converge to around $0.157$, and graphing the points of the sequence, it looks like it's endlessly spiraling around the origin, which suggests that the sequence diverges.

I came up with this example as an attempt to find a bounded sequence that is not Cezàro convergent, which I guessed could be $y_n = e^{2\pi i H_n}$. I have found an other answer, but I'm curious about this one. Essentially the idea is that since $y_n$ circles around the origin infinitely many times, one would think that $x_n$ would too, assuming the norm converges to something greater than $0$, hence divergence. But we're struggling to show both these points.

Comment: It is known that the sequence does not converge for logn. So it would also not converge for H_n.

Comment: The fact about logn can be found in "Aufgaben und Lehrsätze aus der Analysis" by Polya and Szegö, Vol. 1., II, §4.  Perhaps also in Kuipers and Niederreiter "Uniform distribution of sequences".

Comment: @JohannCigler Do you happen to know what value the magnitude converges to?

Comment: At $n=10000$, python gives $0.15714830635513727$, and plugging it into wolfram says it's very close to $\pi / 20$, if that means anything.